# PHP selection in dropdown list

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I need to create  4 dropdown list where the options are the names of the candidates (ex. 5 candidates) in a certain position (ex.Representatives). When i select a candidate from the list in the first dropdown, there will be 4 options in the second dropdown, and in the third dropdown there will be 3 options and so on. To sum it up, what is the php code for removing the list in the next dropdown upon selection without submitting it yet.

Comment: PHP doesn't react with HTML, it is done server side before sending HTML page. You should use JS

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery......jQuery help you to do validations easily. So it may take less time for client side validation

For e.g.;

```
$("#id_of_dropdown").change(function () {
 // Some Code Here like you want to change another dropdown put if else here

});
```